# Angular HTTP Interceptor test fails while the interceptor works fine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http-headers, karma-jasmine, angular-http-interceptors

I am writing unit tests for an angular-12 application using karma-jasmine. And, I am still blocked in the HTTP interceptor tests. The role of this interceptor is to add a token to the header of any request to the server. It works fine on the browser, the token is added and I get the response from the server. However, the unit test fails and no authorization is found in the header of my request.

Below is the code of my testing file, What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

```
describe('JwtInterceptor', () => {
  let client: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let interceptor: JwtInterceptor;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        JwtInterceptor,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: JwtInterceptor,
          multi: true
        }
      ],
    });
    client = TestBed.inject(HttpClient)
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    interceptor = TestBed.inject(JwtInterceptor);
  });

  it('should be created', () => { /** This test succeed */
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should add an Authorization header',() => { /** This is the test that fails */
    client.get('my-api-url')
          .subscribe((response)=>{
            expect(response).toBeTruthy();
          })         
    const httpRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne('my-api-url');
    expect(httpRequest.request.headers.has('Authorization')).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your interceptor? My guess is interceptor only adds token if it has one, and in your case there is no JWT token in tests defined.

Comment: Yes, it is, and adding local storage mock solved the problem, thanks. But, Is there any way so that my test file reads the local storage of my browser?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it shouldn't anyway. You CI won't have a token - unit tests should be isolated and all required data provided to them in the tests.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any of your service methods to make http request. This one  it can verify interceptor properly. Also don't forgot to provide apiUrl in the TestBed configuration.

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {API_URL, JwtInterceptor} from './jwt.interceptor';
import {DataService} from './data.service';

describe('JwtInterceptor', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let service: DataService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        DataService,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: JwtInterceptor,
          multi: true
        },
        {
          provide: API_URL,
          useValue: {apiUrl: 'localhost'}
        }]
    });
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(DataService);
// for localstorage mocking
let store = {};
const mockLocalStorage = {
  getItem: (key: string): string => {
    return key in store ? store[key] : null;
  },
  setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
    store[key] = `${value}`;
  },
  removeItem: (key: string) => {
    delete store[key];
  },
  clear: () => {
    store = {};
  }
};
spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.getItem);
spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.setItem);
spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.removeItem);
spyOn(localStorage, 'clear').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.clear);
});



  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });



  describe('making http calls', () => {
    it('adds authorization header', () => {
      const apiUrl = TestBed.get(API_URL);
      service.getData().subscribe(response => {
        expect(response).toBeTruthy();
      });

  localStorage.setItem('auth_token', 'any auth token here');
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(apiUrl + '/getData');
  expect(req.request.headers.has('Authorization')).toEqual(true);
  expect(req.request.headers.get('Authorization')).toEqual(`Bearer ${authToken}`);
  });
 });

});
```

Comment: Yes, adding local storage mock solved the problem even without using a service, thank you. But, Is there any way so that my test file reads the local storage of my browser?

Comment: i didn't get the point of ur questions !?.
 => localStorage.setItem('auth_token', 'any auth token here');
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(apiUrl + '/getData');
  expect(req.request.headers.has('Authorization')).toEqual(true);
  expect(req.request.headers.get('Authorization')).toEqual(`Bearer ${authToken}`);

Comment: Or you can just mock service that is called by interceptor.

Comment: Thinking If I want to test my services functions, which call the server APIs, where headers should contain authorization, I have to create mock storage just like while testing the interceptor to get a response with data and not a 401 Unauthorized error?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean, @BojanKogoj, Can you explain more or have you an example?

Comment: @ZohraBelkhiria this article will help u a lot 
https://dev.to/alisaduncan/intercepting-http-requests---using-and-testing-angulars-httpclient

Comment: Difficult without seeing how your interceptor works.

Comment: @BojanKogoj, it just takes the original request, clones it using `request.clone()` ( with setting the authorization header), and returns the new request.